# Using CSV files with Bolt CMS

Tags: csv, twig, bolt-cms

I have just recently began working with the Bolt CMS, and so far have had a pleasurable experience.  I am developing an application in which I need to read data from a CSV file and then use that data to dynamically create content in the application.  I have poked around the documentation some, but I have not been able to find anything that has helped.  What would I need to do to be able to do this?  Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible right now… but interestingly enough I committed the start of the command line import/export functionality yesterday. At this stage it only handles YAML files, but JSON is coming over the weekend.

That said, a simple extension that does `file()` read and then use that, e.g.:

```
$values = file('myfile.csv');

// now create an associative array to use below

$record = $this->app['storage']->getEmptyContent($contenttypeslug);
$record->setValues($values);

$id = $this->app['storage']->saveContent($record);
```

**Edit:**

To use existing (and experimental) YAML import functionality, you could transform you CSV structure to look like this and you'd be good with current (master branch) functionality:

```
-    pages:
        slug: about-us
        status: published
        title: 'About Us!'
        image:
            file: logo.jpg
-    entries:
        status: draft
        title: 'Latest stuff to land'
        image:
            file: spaceship.jpg
```

Comment: Do you think one approach that would work would be to convert the csv file to a yaml file, and then use command line functionality you are working on?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance on this, but where would I put this yaml file in the application file structure to where I would have access to the data? I'm not even sure if that question makes much since, but thanks for the additional info in the edit.

Comment: Apologies on the delay in responding. I hoped to have an updated push ready before I replied but that might be a day away.  The `./app/nut database:import --file=/tmp/myfile.yml` command it the one you want. But please be warned that the format will change a bit with the upcoming commit.